# Android: Centralized TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, center, tablelayout, tablerow

Please take a look at this XML code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">

    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
        <ImageButton
        <!-- Some Code -->
        />
        <ImageButton
        <!-- Some Code -->
        />
        <ImageButton
        <!-- Some Code -->
        />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The three ImageButtons are displayed fine in my device (Centralized exactly). However, when I test the app in another device with larger screen, the three images seems to be aligned to the left.

**Is there a way to make the layout centralized? No matter what the screen width is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it.. if i have understood your problem in right manner...

```
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:gravity="center_Horizontal|Center_Vertical">
 <TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_Horizontal|Center_Vertical"
>
```

Comment: `android:gravity="center_Horizontal"` in the TableRow solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

wrap with linearlayout every image button in similar format    . set gravity for each linearlayout to be center. and layout width = fill_parent for all linearlayouts.